Microsoft OneDrive download files
I'm googling different ways regarding how to download files from my personal OneDrive accounts.
I have these problems:
The following code requires code parameter, I googled a lot but didn't find anything what's the code and how to find or get it:
import requests

token_params = {
    'client_id': 'ClientID',
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
    'client_secret': 'ClientSecret',
    'redirect_uri': 'https://jwt.ms'
}

tenant = 'TenantID'
token = token = requests.post(url=f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token', data=token_params)

response:
"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: \'code\'.

Before this, I tried the following code which requires refresh_token, so I had to run the above code:
import requests

params = {
          'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
          'client_id': 'ClientID',
          'refresh_token': ''
         }

response = requests.post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token', data=params)

response:
"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: \'refresh_token\'.

I'm finally going to download all files from OneDrive, but I think I should pass these steps, and unfortunately I couldn't find a way to reach.
One of the questions I saw its answers is this. I closed other tabs and I don't have them to add them in the question.

one of image in your links show value for code which looks similar to value for rereshToken. Maybe you have to use access_token as code.

See official documentation for OneDrive API and Code Flow. It need to open page with special url - and probably it displays page with details about your application and it asks user (it doesn't have to be you) if it allow this application to access his/her data on OneDrive - and it may gives code which application has to use to access data. This way you may create application which I could use to access my files on my OneDrive (instead of your file on your OonDrive)

@furas thanks, I've been trying all of them, but no success yet:( It seems the code value is the response of a URL, but I'm doing as the docs says (I hope), but no luck yet:(

maybe you should use existing Python module (created by Microsoft) onedrive-sdk-python. There is even example which first generates URL, you have to open this url and login, and it gives code which you have to put in code (example uses input() to as for this code).

@furas I finally am able to obtain the code, but it seems I should open it manually in the web browser, and login as a normal user:( Also thanks for the module but it's deprecated and raises error.

yes, as I said before: you have to open URL manually, and copy code manually to script. But you have to do it only once. And it gives access to your files. If I would generate code then it would gives access to my files, not yours. This way this program can be used by different users.

@furas thanks yes you're right. One thing I doubt is that if I should run this URL manually in the future, and then it won't be automated anymore. If the code value is a one-time value, then I think that'll be OK for me. I'll go through this to find.

most APIs are created rather for other web pages - if you would create it as web page then script could easily redirect to this URL and API would send this code automatically to your url (which you defined when you created app on OneDrive page). And all would be automated. For desktop application some solution could be to use GUI framework which has widget to display web page - ie QtWebKit - and display URL in this widget, and later automatically get code displayed in this widget. But if you create it for single person then it is simpler to copy code manually :)
